# Irreducibility of the $k$-secant variety of the Veronese variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read that the $k$-secant variety $\sigma_{k}(V_{d}^{n})$ of the Veronese variety $V_{d}^{n}$ is irreducible, but I do not know how to prove it.

If $k=2$, it is clear, because the variety of secant lines of any irreducible variety is irreducible (see for example Harris' *Algebraic Geometry: A first Course*). Now, I do not know if it is true that the $k$-secant variety of any irreducible variety is irreducible for $k>2$.

I have tried to prove that at least $\sigma_{k}(V_{d}^{n})$ is irreducible considering some incidence correspondences and morphisms, but I have not been able to get anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See p. 102 of "Tangents and Secants of Algebraic Varieties" by F. L. Zak

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland first of all, thanks for your help. Now, in that article it is said that the $k$-secant varieties are clearly irreducible for all $k$. I still do not see why this is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From pp. 87-88 of "On the superadditivity of secant defects" by B. Fantechi *Bull. Soc. Math. France* 118 (1990), 85—100.

> We shall denote by ${\mathbb P}^N$ the $N$-dimensional projective space over a fixed algebraically closed field $k$. If $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ are subsets of ${\mathbb P}^N$, we shall denote by $\langle X_1, \ldots , X_n\rangle$ their linear span, i.e. the smallest projective subspace of ${\mathbb P}^N$ containing all the $X_j$’s.
>
> **Definition 1.1.** — Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be irreducible subvarieties of ${\mathbb P}^N$, and let
>
> $h = \operatorname{max} \{\operatorname{dim}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle | x_j \in X_j\}$·
>
> We denote by $S(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ the closure in $X_1 \times\cdots \times X_n \times {\mathbb P}^N$ of the set
>
> ($\bigstar$) $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n,z) | z \in \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle, \operatorname{dim}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle = h\}$.
>
> The projection of $S(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ in ${\mathbb P}^N$ will be called the join of $X_1,...,X_n$ and will be denoted by $J(X_1,...,X_n)$.
>
> **Remark 1.2.** — Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be irreducible subvarieties of ${\mathbb P}^N$ . Then the following hold :
>
> (i) $S(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ is irreducible ;
>
> (ii) $J(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ is irreducible ;
>
> (iii) $\operatorname{dim} S(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=h+\sum \operatorname{dim}X_j$;
>
> (iv) If $X_1 \cup X_2$ contains at least two distinct points
>
> $\operatorname{dim} S(X_1,X_2) = \operatorname{dim}X_1 + \operatorname{dim}X_2 + 1$.
>
> **Proof.** — Let $\pi$ denote the natural map from $S(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ to $X_1\times\ldots\times X_n$.
>   (i) and (iii) both follow by observing that the open set defined in ($\bigstar$) is a projective bundle of rank $h$ over the set $\{(x_1,\ldots ,x_n) | \operatorname{dim}\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle = h\}$, which is open in $X \times\cdots\times X$.
>   (ii) is a consequence of (i), and (iv) is a consequence of (iii).

[...]

> **Definition 1.5.** — Let $X$ in ${\mathbb P}^N$ be an irreducible variety. We denote $S(X,...,X)$ ($k$ copies) by $S^k(X)$; in the same way we denote $J(X,...,X)$ by $J^k(X)$. $J^k(X)$ will be called $k$-th secant variety of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My knowledge about algebraic geometry is rather limited, and I do not see why "$\{(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n},z)|z\in\langle x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}\rangle, \mathrm{dim}\langle x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\rangle=h\}$ is a projective bundle of rank $h$ over the set $\{(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})|\mathrm{dim}\langle x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\rangle=h\}$" implies that "$S_{k}(X)$ is irreducible".

Comment: @Gauloises: Open in irreducible is irreducible. Product of irreducibles is irreducible. So the key seems to be "which is open in $X\times\cdots\times X$".

Comment: So, $\{(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})|\mathrm{dim}\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\rangle=h\}$ is irreducible because it is open in the irreducible variety $X\times\overset{k)}{\cdots}\times X$. 

Now, the Zariski closure of an irreducible set is also irreducible. According to this, if we prove that $\{(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},z)|z\in\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\rangle, \mathrm{dim}\langle x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\rangle=h\}$ is irreducible, we would have prove that $S_{k}(X)$ is irreducible.

Why is this set irreducible?

Comment: @Gauloises: The total space of a projective bundle over irreducible base is irreducible. That certainly is true for a trivial one (just a product of the base and a projective space). The general case escapes me for the moment, but I don't think this is hard.

Comment: One more thing, how do we know $\{(x_{1},…,x_{n})|\mathrm{dim}⟨x_{1},…,x_{n}⟩=h\}$ is an open subset?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland : If $E$ is a projective bundle $f : E \to X$ over the irreducible base $X$, pick a open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $f^{-1}(U) \to X$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle $U \times \mathbb P^n \to U$, so that $f^{-1}(U)$ is irreducible. Since $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (hence dense in $E$), $E$ is irreducible.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva it seems to me that your last sentence is a bit circular. How do you know that an open set in E is dense in E without knowing that E is irreducible? Don't you have to argue that f is open (which I think it is, because locally it is composition of a trivialisation and a projection from a usual product) and therefore the preimage of a dense set is also dense?

Comment: @Pedro : Let V be another trivializing open subset of X for the bundle E. Since U is dense in X, U cap V is dense in V, so f^{-1}(U) cap f^{-1}(V) is dense in f^{-1}(V) since the bundle is trivial on V. This shows that f^{-1}(U) is dense when intersected with an open cover of E, so it is dense. (I'm not quite sure you need V to be trivializing in this argument, but it certainly works if you assume it!)

Comment: Maybe I had something in mind when I wrote this back then, but I can't figure out what at the moment. I hope my comment clears things for you!

Comment: It does, and your argument seems cleaner than mine. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm also struggling with this. First of all, isn't the condition "$\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \rangle$ has dimension $n-1$" an open one in? Since it is the same as the condition "$x_i \notin \langle x_1, \ldots, \hat{x_i}, \ldots, x_n \rangle$ for all i". I'm saying this because I don't understand why you have to define such $h = \max \ldots$

Comment: Second, I'm having trouble showing that the open set defined in $(\star)$ is a projective bundle (which are the trivializing open sets???).